# ip address and command logs for git clone, pull and push

Tags: git, gitolite

Is there a way to keep track of which user did git clone, pull and push from which ip address from a remote git repository?

If not default git then is it possible with gitolite or other similar tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, gitolite can keep this role (Git alone does not provide any auditing function)

The `~git/.gitolite/logs` folder will include logs of events, including clone, push, pull.
See "[4.4 gitolite files and directories](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/files.html#special-files)".

Other Git repo manager like GitLab does support audit events, but that would be [only the EE (Enterprise Edition), not CE (Community Edition)](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/9539).